# How to conver a SQL query from MySQL 8 to MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I fix this code to MySQL 5.7?

```
with recursive u as
(select t.id, t.refferal, t.balance from users t where refferal = 1
union
select t.id, t.refferal, t.balance from u inner join users t
on u.id = t.refferal)
(select u.id,u.refferal,u.balance from u)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=caec6dd3f96f444e82387878d88e8c19)

Comment: One workaround is to use the [now obsolete] variables, but it's not fool proof. The other solution is to write a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) answer:

```
select  id,
        refferal,
        balance
from    (select * from users
         order by refferal, id) u,
        (select @pv := 1) v
where   find_in_set(refferal, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=552e5b6f662e0008e24bab06ca63c90a)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this query if refferal < id will return to null

[link]https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=02f2141ddacc84f1dc197d68ac67ed3c

Comment: @Pisit it returns the same result as your other query! [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02f2141ddacc84f1dc197d68ac67ed3c)

Comment: Do you have a way to return results without this condition? (refferal is greater or less than id)

Comment: @Pisit maybe what you're looking for (in your recursive query) is `where t.id = 10` instead of `where t.refferal = 10` ? Since there are no users with refferal = 10...